# Why is JSON.parse not working for "23232323."?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this field

```
text = "23232323."
```

and for validation I want to get it like this `23232323.`

I am trying with `JSON.parse(text)` giving `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: missing digits after decimal point`

and `eval(text)` is giving `23232323`

How can I fix it?

Comment: If that's all your JSON string, it isn't valid. JSON needs to be enclosed in `{}` or `[]`. What's your *exact* data?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario That's not the problem. Try `JSON.parse("3")`.

Comment: @dystroy: True, it probably works with a lot of parsers. However, according to RFC, an array or object should be at the top level. At least that's how I understand section 2: *"A JSON text is a serialized object or array."* (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

Comment: @dystroy - Try both `JSON.parse("23232323.")` and `JSON.parse('{"foo": "23232323."}')`. The *exact* syntax is important when you get a syntax error.

Comment: I don't think this is "blind speculation", any JSON parser, when parsing `23232323.`, should raise an error and the smartest ones should precise it's because of *"missing digits after decimal point"* while, just like OP precises, `eval('23232323.')` would do just what he expects.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario OP's question explicitly states that he does `JSON.parse("23232323.")`.

Comment: @dystroy - That wasn't clear until you fixed the code formatting—so thanks for the edit ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can't be parsed because, contrary to popular belief, JSON is a strongly defined language and you can't simply put anything that you could eval.

Here's how numbers are defined :

[image]

(see [json.org](http://www.json.org/))

You can solve the problem by removing the dot at the end or, better, by not putting it in the first place. Of course, if you trust the source, you can simply use `eval('('+yourstring+')')` too.